# How to get nontext, non-attachment content with MailKit?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, mimekit

We have a system where we receive data via email sent to an OutLook365 address, and we have a POP3/IMAP client that reads these emails and processes the contents.

We're working in .NET, and we're using MailKit to retrieve the emails.

The crux of what we're doing:

```
MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client client = constructClient();

for (var i = 0; i < client?.Count ?? 0; i++)
{
    MimeMessage message = client.GetMessage(i);

    var attachments = new List<OurAttachmentObject>();

    foreach (MimeEntity mimeEntity in message.Attachments)
    {
        attachments.Add(constructOurAttachmentObj(mimeEntity);
    }

    var messageMessageId = message.MessageId;
    var messageHtmlBody = message.HtmlBody;
    var messageTextBody = message.TextBody;

    doSomething(messageMessageId, messageHtmlBody, messageTextBody, attachments);
}
```

And here's the thing - we have one customer whose emails are ending up empty:

- MimeMessage.HtmlBody is null, and
- MimeMessage.TextBody is null, and
- MimeMessage.Attachments is empty.

Our code will process an attachment. Or a TextBody or an HtmlBody. But we expect at least one of these to be present.

The weirdness is that this only happens when *they* send us the email. When we copy the email within Outlook, so we can send it again, it works. When we send an email with the same contents, it works. It's only when they send the email that we have this problem.

What they are sending:

```
Received: from [...]
From:  [...]
To:  [...]
Date:  [...]
Subject:  [...]
Message-ID:  [...]
X-Mailer: [...]
Content-Type: Text/XML; name=theirfilename.xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
[...]
MIME-Version: 1.0

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TheirXmlElement>
  [...]
</TheirXmlElement>

.
```

Yes, the body of the email is XML.

When we look at it in Outlook365, the XML is displayed as an attachment, and when we copy the email within Outlook, it comes in as an attachment:

```
Received: [...]
From: [...]
To: [...]
Subject: [...]
Thread-Topic: [...]
Thread-Index: [...]
[...]
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="_002_20201109124249401C297454xxxxx_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_002_20201109124249401C297454xxxxx_--
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"


--_002_20201109124249401C297454xxxxx_--
Content-Type: text/xml; name="theirfilename.xml"
Content-Description: theirfilename.xml
Content-Disposition: attachment;
  filename="theirfilename.xml"; size=11788;
  creation-date="Mon, 09 Nov 2020 19:42:56 GMT";
  modification-date="Mon, 09 Nov 2020 19:42:56 GMT"
Content-ID: <F4B1CA23B7E98F49BCD9AC9B82024AF1@namprd17.prod.outlook.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+DQo8TmV3RGF0YVNldD4NCiAgPGRlbGl2ZXJ5Pg0KICAgIDxj
[...]
M24NCiAgICA8L3ByaW50YWJsZV90ZXh0Pg0KICA8L3RpY2tldHM+DQo8L05ld0RhdGFTZXQ+DQoN
Cg==

--_002_20201109124249401C297454xxxxx_--
.
```

And our code handles attachments just fine.

When we test by pasting the XML contents into a plain email, what receive is:

```
Received: [...]
From: [...]
To: [...]
Subject: [...]
Thread-Topic: [...]
Thread-Index: [...]
[...]
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TheirXmlElement>
  [...]
</TheirXmlElement>

.
```

And that shows up in MimeMessage.TextBody, which our code also handles fine.

The problem seems to be that because the Content-Type is Text/XML, the body isn't being placed into MimeMessage.TextBody, but it's not being treated as an attachment, either. Though OutLook will do exactly that if you copy the message around.

What I have discovered, in debugging this, is that when we receive one of their tickets, where MimeMessage.TextBody is null, and MimeMessage.HtmlBody is null, and MimeMessage.Attachments is empty, I can retrieve the body of the email with:

```
messageTextBody = message.Body.ToString();
```

But that worries me. MimeMessage.Body is a MimeEntity, and I wouldn't expect .ToString() to work on it, all of the time.

How *does* MimeKit expect clients to extract the body of an email, when it's not text, or html, or an attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBody`, `HtmlBody`, and `Attachments` properties are there only for convenience for common message structures.

What you need to do is to walk the tree structure of the MIME message body.

This is all explained in the FAQ: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#q-how-can-i-get-the-main-body-of-a-message

In your particular case, you could probably fall back to this:

```
var body = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().FirstOrDefault();
var text = body.Text;
```

P.S. You should definitely *not* use `message.Body.ToString()`.

Comment: That works - except that includes that trailing "." line, which makes the result invalid XML.

So I'm trimming off everything before "<?xml" and everything after the last ">".

It would have been easier if they'd simply properly mime-wrapped the body.